# Simplifying floor > $ \left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor}{2}}\right \rfloor= \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2^2}}\right \rfloor$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is the following true

> $ \left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor}{2}}\right \rfloor= \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2^2}}\right \rfloor$

for all $n \in \mathbb{I}$

Comment: Is n an integer?

Comment: @samjoe yes it is

Comment: Then say so in the original question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Test with $n=4a,4a+1,4a+2,4a+3$ where $a$ is an integer

For all the case

$$\left\lfloor\dfrac n4\right\rfloor=a$$

$$\left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor}{2}}\right \rfloor=?$$

Comment: Alright, I guess it is not true for any integer, then how does $ \left \lfloor{\frac{\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor}{2}}\right \rfloor $ simplify if at all

Comment: @glockm15, Why not any? If $n=4a+3$  $$\left\lfloor\dfrac n2\right\rfloor=2a+1$$ and $$\left\lfloor\dfrac n4\right\rfloor=a$$

Comment: Ops, my bad, I used $a$ for the second floor function instead of $n$. Got it thanks, so the equation is true